# When modal opens using <a> tag if makes a form on my DOM disappear for no apparent reason

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I use the code below inside an  tag to open a modal. The code works great, but when the modal opens it erases everything inside my `<form>` tag below. Does anyone know why? I've changed the `<a>` tag to `<p>`, `<div>` etc and it does the same thing.

```
<a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#siteModal" onclick="build_post_modal()">
    <form id="post_template" method="POST">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <div class="text-danger my-2" id="csrf_token-error"></div>
        <div class="post d-flex align-items-center">
            <img src="{{ current_user.avatar(50) }}" width="50" class="rounded-circle mr-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.body.label }}
                {{ form.body(class='form-control', placeholder='Make a post...') }}
                <div id="body-error" class="invalid-feedback"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</a>
```

The modal opens just fine, but when it does everything in the  tag is erased from the DOM. Here is my build_post_modal function.

```
function build_post_modal(csrf_token) {
    post_template=document.getElementById('post_template')

    $("#modal-title").html("Post");
    $("#modal-body").html(post_template);
    footer="<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-secondary\" data-bs-dismiss=\"modal\">Close</button>"
    $("#modal-footer").html(footer);

    const fields = {
        csrf_token: {
            input: document.getElementById('csrf_token'),
            error: document.getElementById('csrf_token-error')
        },
        body: {
            input: document.getElementById('body'),
            error: document.getElementById('body-error')
        }
    }
    post_template.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const response = await fetch('/_submit_post', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                csrf_token: fields.csrf_token.input.value,
                body: fields.body.input.value
            })
        });
        if (response.ok) {
            $('#siteModal').modal('hide')
            jFlash(await response.text())
        } else {
            const errors = await response.json();
            Object.keys(errors).forEach((key) => {
               fields[key].input.classList.add('is-invalid');
               fields[key].error.innerHTML = errors[key][0];
            });
        }
    });

};
```

Comment: This line is the one causing the problem: `$("#modal-body").html(post_template);`. When you pass a DOM node into it, jQuery will **move** the DOM node into `#modal-body`, causing it to disappear from the button. The question is: why do you need to dynamically populate the modal? Can you not create a custom modal for the form, and paste the form markup in the modal body directly, instead of moving DOM nodes around?

Comment: Thanks for that! I am going to try and clone the node into a hidden area and then pull that into the modal. I can't think of an easier way to get the modal constructed with the csrf token easily.

Comment: Thanks @Terry I blended your solution. I just made a hidden html piece that I pull into the modal. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Taking advantage of what Terry pointed out I rewrote the code as follows:

```
<a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#siteModal" onclick="build_post_modal()">
    <div class="post d-flex align-items-center">
        <img src="{{ current_user.avatar(50) }}" width="50" class="rounded-circle mr-2">
        <input class="form-control" id="post_body" placeholder="Make a post..." type="text" value="">
    </div>
</a>
<div id="post_modal" style="display: none;">
    <form id="post_template" method="POST">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <div class="text-danger my-2" id="csrf_token-error"></div>
        <div class="post d-flex align-items-center">
            <img src="{{ current_user.avatar(50) }}" width="50" class="rounded-circle mr-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.body.label }}
                {{ form.body(class='form-control', placeholder='Make a post...') }}
                <div id="body-error" class="invalid-feedback"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and I changed the build_modal function to this:

```
function build_post_modal() {
    post_template=document.getElementById('post_template')
    //post_template.setAttribute("style", "display: block")

    $("#modal-title").html("Post");
    $("#modal-body").html(post_template);
    footer="<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-secondary\" data-bs-dismiss=\"modal\">Close</button>"
    $("#modal-footer").html(footer);

    const fields = {
        csrf_token: {
            input: document.getElementById('csrf_token'),
            error: document.getElementById('csrf_token-error')
        },
        body: {
            input: document.getElementById('body'),
            error: document.getElementById('body-error')
        }
    }
    post_template.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const response = await fetch('/_submit_post', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                csrf_token: fields.csrf_token.input.value,
                body: fields.body.input.value
            })
        });
        if (response.ok) {
            $('#siteModal').modal('hide')
            jFlash(await response.text())
        } else {
            const errors = await response.json();
            Object.keys(errors).forEach((key) => {
               fields[key].input.classList.add('is-invalid');
               fields[key].error.innerHTML = errors[key][0];
            });
        }
    });

};
```

This allows me to copy a hidden post element that has my CSRF token and html formatting into the modal I like. When the dom pulls the html to the modal it isn't apparent to the user and I can place it back once my function is done running.